# Do I need to play past a certain point to play online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I've read that you need to play at least the prologue of the single player to play GTA online. Is this the case for the PC (Steam) version?

Also does playing only multiplayer and ignoring single player spoil any of the single player missions/story?

I've never played GTA 5 before so no spoilers or anything like that please!

Comment: I haven't tried, but when launching the game, there's an option to choose GTA V Single Player or GTA Online. Also, when you launch the game, on the main menu, you can choose either online or story, so I don't think there are any requirements for Online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that you are indeed required to complete the prologue of the game before you can play online on PC. I tried to jump straight into online and was in turn, forced to complete the prologue. (a relatively painless experience)

In theory it shouldn't directly disrupt the missions or story, but you do deal with story characters to collect some of the more fun online missions and these tend to coincide with their single player counterparts.

You could always just do the unrelated missions such as Team Deathmatch or Races.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying that as well as answering the second half of the question i appreciate it. I don't suppose you know at what point in the single player campaign all the relevant story related characters have been introduced that make an appearance in the online?

Comment: It seems you have to get to Franklin's bedroom (first save point) before starting multiplayer, which means doing the initial snowy bank robbery thing and the first mission with Franklin and Lamar and sportscars first. ... Also, Online takes place before V so you won't run into any spoilers, you might just learn the setting and contact personalities and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically play online. While it is recommended that you at LEAST play the prologue/tutorial you have the freedom to immediately jump into Multiplayer.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is incorrect, you have to complete the prologue before you can play.